# What is meant by an integral with $\Omega$ as its range: $\int_{\Omega}$

Tags: calculus, notation

What does it mean when $\Omega$ is range of integral?

$$\iint  G \frac{\partial U}{\partial n} - U(J k G) ds  =\int_{\Omega}{G\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial n} -j k U\right)R^2 dw} $$

I do not understand what Omega signify in terms of region.  Please Help

Comment: $\Omega$ is just a region over which you're integrating. In one dimension, it would be a line segment, in two dimensions it would be an area, in three it would be a volume (and so on).

Comment: my book use this tranformation,

Comment: In this case, $\Omega$ is some area in the $xy$ plane over which you're integrating.

Comment: ok, appreciate your help